# How can i redirect a user to the PCP link once they login

Tags: pcp

I have added a note to the top of **create a PCP page** on the thank you event page. [image: Thank you page] I have added this note in the custom template file ThankYou.tpl. For "here" i have added a href= /user, however if they login it just shows only the account information. How can i redirect user to access the PCP pages once they login. Please help, I am a newbie and do not know much about smarty template customization and CiviCRM. BTW site is Drupal 7.

Comment: hi do you want to display the PCP page or do you want to redirect to the actual page ?

Comment: I want to Display the actual page (Thank you page), so the user can click on create a PCP page link to access the page.

Comment: Is that possible to keep the user on the same thank you page once they login.

Answer (score 1):

You wont be able to redirect back to the thank you page, as the thank you page URL is dynamic (with _qfkey, etc.)

**Alternative solution:**

You can use the URL of the create personal campaign page as the destination after login.

In the href for the login page, you can use the below

```
please go <a href="/user?destination=%2Fcivicrm%2Fcontribute%2Fcampaign%3Faction%3Dadd%26reset%3D1%26pageId%3D1%26component%3Dcontribute">here<a> to login
```

Note: The value for 'destination' query paramater should be encoded for the redirect to work correctly for any CiviCRM URLs.

So after login, the user will be redirected to the create personal campaign page directly. This will also avoid an extra button click in the user journey you are expecting (i.e after login redirect back to thankyou page and then the user click 'Create personal campaign page' button which then takes the user to create personal campaign page.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable PCP in the Contribution/event page setup

also please refer to the below link for creating own PCP page in the thank you page 
https://book.civicrm.org/user/current/contributions/personal-campaign-pages/

Please click this link for example 
http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=2

I guess this helps